# Get type of object in object even if the object type can be undefined

Tags: typescript

I have this type:

```
type MyType = {
  a?: {
     b: number;
  }
}
```

I want to get the type of `b`.

Then I want to build another type like that:

```
type AnotherType = {
  mytype: MyType['a']['b']
}
```

But this doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NonNullable`:

```
type AnotherType = {
  mytype: NonNullable<MyType['a']>['b']
}
```

Or `Required`:

```
type AnotherType = {
  mytype: Required<MyType>['a']['b']
}
```